# Assigning file access rights to IIS_IUSRS using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-access

I'm trying to add access rights for the user group `IIS_IUSRS` to a folder using PowerShell.

Currently I have

```
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS", "FullControl", "Allow")
$acl = Get-ACL "C:\tmp"
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-ACL -Path "C:\tmp" -ACLObject $acl
```

When run, this adds IIS_IUSRS to the list of users but there are no privileges assigned.

[image]

What have I missed?

Comment: I think you need to use the `-SecurityDescriptor` parameter instead, or maybe one of the properties of your `$acl` object

Comment: @trebleCode Where? What?

Comment: Was just looking through the help for the cmdlet which states:

`To use Set-Acl , use the Path or InputObject parameter to identify the item whose security descriptor you want to change. Then, use the AclObject or SecurityDescriptor parameter to supply a
security descriptor that has the values you want to apply. Set-Acl applies the security descriptor that is supplied. It uses the value of the AclObject parameter as a model and changes the
values in the item's security descriptor to match the values in the AclObject parameter.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On my system i needed to use just `IIS_IUSRS`, so drop the `BUILTIN\`.
Furthermore, I think you need to construct the FileSystemAccessRule with extra parameters `inheritanceFlags` and `propagationFlags` to get what you want.

Try this:

```
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl = Get-ACL "C:\tmp"
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-ACL -Path "C:\tmp" -ACLObject $acl
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think those additional properties are optional - here's the docs for the overload that I was using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147784(v=vs.110).aspx
I tried yours - literally copy/pasted it - and it has the same result: the user is added but none of the privilege checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Aha, i've been fiddling with these flags and seem to have copied the wrong ones. I have edited my answer with the correct flags. For me this works: `$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")`

Comment: This only worked for me when I removed this 2 parameters: ```"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None"```